# Black lines on National Instruments ImageViewer control

Tags: camera, computer-vision, labview

I'm using Point Grey GigE Blackfly cameras and the National Instruments Vision Acquisition Imaqdx namespace though C#. I've got a two loops, each in their own thread, that read from the camera and set the image in a winforms ImageViewer object.

More or less, two of these

```
NationalInstruments.Vision.Acquisition.Imaqdx.ImaqdxSession _imaq;
NationalInstruments.Vision.WindowsForms.ImageViewer _imageViewer;
...
while(true)
    _imaq.Grab(_imageViewer.Image, waitForNextBuffer: true);
```

It works, but the images from the cameras have these black lines on them. Not unlike this-
[image]

It gets worse as the number of cameras I connect to increases. After four cameras, it's mostly black lines.

I've got jumbo packets set to 9014 bytes in my network adapter settings. The camera is set to use 8000 byte packets. There's another 200 attributes on the camera and ImageViewer control, but I've not found any that help and I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be encountering a bandwidth limit in the network.

How much bandwidth do your cameras require with their current settings? Does it help if you [tune them to share](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/EC76AC9B636C6B63862575480003BBFF)?

Comment: "If the maximum bandwidth is exceeded, you will begin to experience data loss.  This can be expressed in many ways, but it is most common to see black or green lines/bands flash across the image."
That was good to know. Turns out I had dramatically underestimated how much bandwidth a single camera could use. I remember when a giga was a lot of bits. Various methods of dropping the bandwidth used by any given camera fixed it right up. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

YUV Format can cause this kind of problems with multiple cameras in LabVIEW.
If you use this, try another one.